# Linux kernel match any usb device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, usb-drive

I would like to load a module when **any** device is plugged in. My `usb_device_id` is defined as follows:

```
  static struct usb_device_id usb_ids[] = {
     {.driver_info = 42},
     {}
  };
  MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE(usb, usb_ids);
```

According to [Usb driver](https://lwn.net/images/pdf/LDD3/ch13.pdf), `driver_info = 42` should match any usb device plugged into the system and, thus, this module should be loaded.

To install this driver I do the following steps:

- compile the driver
- copy the driver to `/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/kernel/drivers/usb/misc`
- run `depmod -a`

Am I doing something wrong?

I am using a kernel version 3.19. The book I referenced above was written for the kernel version 2.*. Could be that `.driver_info = 42` doesn't work in recent kernels?

Comment: Does your driver get probed if the module is loaded with `modprobe`?

Comment: Yes. And if i use vendor id and product id to match a specific device. It works properly.

Comment: What is the driver's entry in `/lib/modules/(version)/modules.alias`?

Comment: Better to use `extras` or `updates`.